# Make rest of the images smaller except first image

Tags: css

Trying to change the width of the rest of the images with css.

[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/cqe4V/)

what I want to achieve is:

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/cqe4V/1/)

css

```
.left{
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    width: 246px;
}

.wrapper div:first-of-type{
    width: 513px;
}


.left p{
    color: #555555;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

tried few things but not able to achieve the result I need.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the width for all images, and then explicitly define the first image. For example:

```
.wrapper div img {
    width: 246px;
}
.wrapper div:first-child {
    width: 513px;
}
.wrapper div:first-child img {
    width: 513px;
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/cqe4V/5/)

Comment: the content below is still of original width.

Comment: See the edit. It's identical to the layoutyou've posted in what you wish to achieve...

Comment: Someone keeps downvoting. I'd like to know why?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to make your `img` be the size of the container with this :

```
.left img {
  width:100%;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/cqe4V/2/